# mDNS not working for Raspberry Pi Zero W

Tags: networking, mdns, avahi, resolv.conf

So, I've just got a Raspberry Pi Zero W and installed Raspbian Stretch Lite (headless Debian Stretch). I was able to configure WiFi in headless mode and the Raspberry connected to my home WiFi network.

I've then run `nmap 192.168.100.0/24 -p 22` to find out the device's IP:

```
Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-06-07 22:01 +03

Nmap scan report for 192.168.100.57
Host is up (0.0095s latency).

PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh

Nmap done: 256 IP addresses (5 hosts up) scanned in 2.76 seconds
```

Looks like `192.168.100.57` is the droid I am looking for. Connecting over SSH works:

```
ssh pi@192.168.100.57
Linux raspberrypi-1 4.14.98+ #1200 Tue Feb 12 20:11:02 GMT 2019 armv6l

pi@raspberrypi-1:~ $ hostname
raspberrypi-1
```

I've already played a little with it and changed the hostname to `raspberrypi-1`, but everything I'm asking happened with the default name too (`raspberrypi`).

Avahi is running on my Raspberry:

```
pi@raspberrypi-1:~ $ ps axu | grep avahi
avahi      247  0.0  0.7   6384  3168 ?        Ss   17:54   0:00 avahi-daemon: running [raspberrypi-1.local]
avahi      255  0.0  0.3   6384  1480 ?        S    17:54   0:00 avahi-daemon: chroot helper
pi         829  0.0  0.4   4360  2028 pts/0    S+   19:10   0:00 grep --color=auto avahi
```

Self ping by `raspberrypi-1.local` name works too:

```
pi@raspberrypi-1:~ $ ping raspberrypi-1.local
PING raspberrypi-1.local (192.168.100.57) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.100.57 (192.168.100.57): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.230 ms
^C
--- raspberrypi-1.local ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
```

Now, I'm trying to connect to Pi by it's hostname from my laptop:

```
$ ssh pi@raspberrypi-1.local                                                                                                                                                         
ssh: Could not resolve hostname raspberrypi-1.local: Name or service not known
```

But `avahi-resolve` is able to resolve that name!

```
$ avahi-resolve -nv raspberrypi-1.local                                                                                                                                                   
Server version: avahi 0.7; Host name: millennium-falcon.local
raspberrypi-1.local     192.168.100.57
```

However, `avahi-browse -arp` does not show my Pi.

My laptop's `/etc/nsswitch.conf` is:

```
passwd: files mymachines systemd
group: files mymachines systemd
shadow: files

publickey: files

hosts: files mymachines mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] resolve [!UNAVAIL=return] dns mdns4 myhostname
networks: files

protocols: files
services: files
ethers: files
rpc: files

netgroup: files
```

And `/etc/resolv.conf` is:

```
nameserver fe80::1%wlp2s0
nameserver 82.209.240.241
nameserver 82.209.243.241
```

I cannot understand what's wrong with my config and why cannot I connect to the Pi using its hostname. WAIDW?

Answer (score 0):

The issues seems to be gone after creating a `/etc/mdns.allow` file on my laptop:

```
$ ll /etc/mdns.allow                                                                                                                                                                      
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 15 Jun  7 23:56 /etc/mdns.allow
$ cat /etc/mdns.allow                                                                                                                                                                     
.local.
.local
```

I found the solution [here](https://github.com/lathiat/nss-mdns/blob/master/README.md#etcmdnsallow).
Still not sure why it doesn't work by default…